# A question about superposition and zeroing condition

Tags: voltage

> Calculate the voltage \$U_x\$ in the circuit below. Specify zeroing condition of the \$U_x\$ indicated in the figure.

[image]

I know I can solve this with the superposition theorem but I'm confused about the \$U_x\$ place and direction. In addition I'm not really sure about zeroing condition.

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a voltage source E and a current source I. We will calculate the effect of individual sources on Ux. Ux is the voltage drop across the resistor when a current is passed through it, from left to right. Let that current be Ix.

The figure shows the circuit after removing the current source.

[image: schematic]

From figure, $$Ux_1 = E\times \frac{R}{R+R} = E/2 \tag1$$

Now, removing the voltage source,

[image: schematic]

$$Ix = -I\times \frac{R}{R+R} = -I/2$$
$$Ux_2 = IxR = -IR/2\tag2$$

Now \$Ux = Ux_1 + Ux_2 = \dfrac{E-IR}{2}\$

Now Ux can be made zero if E = IR. This is your zeroing condition.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to note:

A resistor accross a voltage source has no effect on the voltage.

A resistor in series with a current source has no effect on the current.

When you have a combination of voltage and current sources, it's often easier to solve the circuit if you convert them all to either current sources (Norton equivalents) or voltage sources (Thevenin equivalents).  Generally I'd start by making everything a voltage source except in unusual situations.

Comment: Is `E` a voltage source? Seeing that symbol, I thought it is a current source.

Comment: @nidhin: It's definitely a voltage source in this context. This should be within whatever conventions have been established in your course or the particular text this is from. The fact that the variable for its value has the name "E", and it's also cleary different from the current source on the right should really make this obvious.

Comment: Hm. The symbol caused the confusion. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: That symbol can often be found in older textbooks, where it stands for electromotive force (at least in Germany). It represents the open-circuit voltage of a voltage source.